# Replacing Div using jQuery .load causes new div links not to work

Tags: ajax, load

I'm replacing a div using jQuery ajax load to load in a new div:

```
    $("td.prod2").click(function(){
     $("#products-details").load("/products/Test.aspx");
    });
```

The new div features an unordered list which replaces the previous unordered list:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="">Link 1</li>
<li><a href="">Link 2</li>
<li><a href="">Link 3</li>
</ul>
```

When I click on the links in the new div, the content from the original div is reloaded onto the page?

Any ideas?

Comment: What do the links in the new div point to? And how is the content from the old divs being loaded in the first place?

Comment: Please explain more. It's confusing.

Comment: The anchor elements in the new div have a blank href and clicking on these links will take the user to the same page which in turn just displays the old div. What are you expecting?

Comment: I left the href's blank for the purpose of explaining the problem. The hrefs in fact point to hidden divs:http://jsfiddle.net/33cqX/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try binding the event using `live` instead. This will make sure that when the DOM changes your new content will have the events...

```
$('td.prod2').live('click', function() {
    $("#products-details").load('/products/Test.aspx');
});
```

This should definitely resolve the problem you're having.

For more details about `live` see: http://api.jquery.com/live/

**UPDATED:** The code you included above looks to be incomplete...What is the content you are loading from '/products/Test.aspx'? I am assuming that it includes a few `<td class="prod2">` that should have this event binded.

Comment: @Geoff: Correct, ```delegate``` is faster as it uses a context and also doesn't execute immediately. I've used ```live``` in my answer as the full markup was included in the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you replace elements that have event listeners, those listeners are then disconnected. You need to reinitialize them or use something like jQuery's `.live()` functionality.